# Are tmp and tests folder of cakephp 3.0 to be uploaded on server?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Do we need to upload **tmp** and **tests** folder of [cakephp 3.0](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/quickstart.html) on server?

If that so, It increases my file size to more than 200MB which is a huge.

I googled but nothing found regarding this and also search on cakephp docs.

Could please suggest on this regards?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tmp` folder - **yes**, it's used for caching, session storage and stuff.

However, there might have been files generated that aren't necessary on your production server, like for example the DebugKit SqLite Database file, error/debug logs, session files, test data, etc, so you may want to sparse them out, or even upload only the empty folder, and let Cake regenerate the necessary stuff on the server.

`test` folder - **no**, not unless you want to actually run the tests on the server.

See also

- **[Cookbook > CakePHP at a Glance > CakePHP Folder Structure](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/cakephp-folder-structure.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Installation > Permissions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#permissions)**
- **[Cookbook > Testing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html)**

Comment: Thanks a lot again.. @ndm, if **tmp** to be considered to upload, there is a **debug_kit.sqlite** file inside **tmp** folder which takes the total sizes. I do not include the **debug_kit** Plugin in my project, so can i delete it from the folder in that case?

Comment: @BayezidAlam Yes, see my edit, there might be files that are not needed, the SQLite Database may be one of them. Theoretically uploading the empty folder structure should be enough, unless your app has specifically generated content in there that it needs for the first run on the server.

Comment: The app write caches and logs to that folder but you don't need to upload it just recreate it on the server.

Comment: @MattStephens Uploading an empty folder and recreating a folder is pretty much the same in a deployment process, isn't it?